# Node Module + PDF Helper -- What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following helper code in a node module for generating pdfs.  It uses the pdfCrowd API and Restler.

```
var rest = require( "restler" );
var create = function() {

    this.pdfConfig = { 
        // data object for generating the pdf
    };

    this.getRaw = function( cb ) {
        this.fetch(function( err, result ) {
            if ( err ) return cb( err );
            cb( null, new Buffer( result.raw ).toString( "base64" ));
        });
    };

    this.fetch = function( cb ) {
        rest.post( "https://pdfcrowd.com/api/pdf/convert/html/", { data: this.pdfConfig })
        .on("success", function( err, result ) {
            if ( err ) return cb( err );
            cb( null, result );
        });
    };

};
module.exports.create = create;
```

I use this helper to send pdfs out as email attachments.

```
var Pdf = require( "/helpers/pdf" ),

function sendPdfEmail() {
    var pdf = new Pdf.create();
    pdf.pdfConfig = { ... }
    pdf.getRaw(function( err, pdfData ) {
       sendEmail( from, to, subject, body, pdfData );
    });
}
```

The trouble is, I have learned that under race conditions, where a lot of people are calling sendPdfEmail(), I might get someone else's PDF.  That is to say, the correct emails are delivered - but the data in the attachment might belong to someone else.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:  As requested, here is further detail on sendEmail.**

sendEmail is another helper which I include.  It is a wrapper for the node-postmark module.

```
   var sendEmail = function( from, to, subject, body, attachment, cb ) {

        var postmark = require( "postmark" )( api_key );
        postmark.send({
            "From": from,
            "To": to,
            "Subject": subject,
            "HtmlBody": body,
            "Attachments": attachment ? [{
              "Content": attachment,
              "Name": "stuff.pdf",
              "ContentType": "application/pdf"
            }] : null
        }, function( err, success ) {
            if ( typeof cb === "function" ) cb();
            postmark = null;
        });

    };
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more than on those `race conditions`? How exactly this code is used?

Comment: Ok, maybe it's just me, but I see nothing wrong here. What about `sendEmail`, how this function is defined? Also, can you show how exactly `pdfConfig` is filled up?

Comment: Again, this is definitely localized. What about `pdfConfig` creation?

Comment: I just set it with data coming in on the request.  For example:  pdf.pdfConfig = { html: transformHtml( req.body.data ) };  transformHtml is also straightforward.  It just passes the data to a jade template and returns the html.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38298/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-user1031947)